# GCC on MinGW: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: c++, gcc, https, mingw, libcurl

I'm using MinGW on Windows 10 Professional.

I installed libcurl with the following commands:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/curl/curl
$ cd curl
$ ./buildconf.bat
$ mingw32-make mingw32
$ cp lib/libcurl.a /c/MinGW/lib
$ cp -r include/curl/ /c/MinGW/include
```

Then I wrote the following toy C++ program to test it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.ecs.rocks/v0/util/removeMessageHeader");
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_free(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it with the following command:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp -o curltest -m32 -DCURL_STATICLIB -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwldap32 -lwsock32 -lwinmm
```

Everything looks good at this point. My pwd now contains a new file named `curltest.exe`.

I try running it:

```sh
$ ./curltest.exe
```

And I get this output:

```
* Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
```

What have I done wrong? How do I enable support for HTTPS in libcurl built from source on MinGW?

Comment: what do you get when you run `pkg-config --libs --flags curl`??

Comment: `bash: pkg-config: command not found`

Comment: After installing pkg-config and running `pkg-config --libs --cflags curl`, I got `Package curl was not found in the pkg-config search path`.

Comment: first which compiler are you using? seems to me that you are using g++, and GNU comes with `pkg-cofig` already as long as long as the environment path is set. I do not know exactly wat happens when you install it separately, though i believe it should be able to detect the installed C++ packages. Since curl is not in the search path, you should include it in the search path in path. Probably you are using a variant of `libcurl`. Sorry I am unable to tell what the issue here is

Answer (score 0):

You have built libcurl without any TLS library.
I suggest you having a look at the [official curl guide](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) on how to build curl on MingW32. It also explains what to do to enable TLS.